# Why can I see the image on the Tkinter canvas only using negative coordinates?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I am new in Python and I am trying to design my first login system using Tkinter. I am struggling a bit with canvas and images. I managed to create a canvas on the right and to put the image on it. I would like to reach something similar to this: [image]

But at the moment, after creating a canvas and putting the image on it, I can see the arrow just when I put negative values on the axis `(-250, -250)`, as you can see on my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image



class Login_system():
    
    user = "user"
    passw = "pw"
    
    def __init__(self, root):


        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Login System Prova")
        self.entry = tk.Entry(root)
        self.root.geometry("425x225")  
        stvar = tk.StringVar()
        stvar.set("one")
        self.option = tk.OptionMenu(root, stvar, "one", "two", "three")
        

        w = 450 
        h = 300
        x = w/2
        y = h/2

        my_canvas = Canvas(root, width = w, heigh = h, bg = "white" )
        my_canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 2, columnspan = 2, rowspan = 2, padx = 3, pady = 2)

        

        img = PhotoImage(file = r"C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Foto\\Haken.png")
        root.img = img
        my_image = my_canvas.create_image((-250, -250), image = img, anchor = NW)

        
         
        frame = Frame(self.root)
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = N, columnspan = 1)


        self.option = tk.OptionMenu(frame, stvar, "one", "two", "three")

        self.option.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = NW)
        
        Label(frame, text = "Your Username").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady = 2)
        self.username = Entry(frame)
        self.username.grid(row = 1, column= 2, pady=2, sticky = NE, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 3)

         
        Label(frame, text = "Your Password").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=NW, pady=2)
        self.password = Entry(frame, show = "*")
        self.password.grid(row = 2, column=2, pady=2, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 3)
        
        
        ttk.Button(frame, text = "Login", command = self.login_user).grid(row = 8, column=1, sticky = W, rowspan = 1)

        
    def login_user(self):

        if self.username.get() == self.user and self.password.get() == self.passw:

            root.destroy()

            #newroot = Tk()
            #application = ...(newroot)
            #newroot.mainloop()

        else:

            self.message = Label(text = "Wrong Username or Password!")
            self.message.grid(row = 1, column = 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Login_system = Login_system(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

And this is what I obtained:

[image]

My questions would be:

1. Why can I see the image on the canvas only when I use negative values as coordinates? How can I reduce the image and put it at the center of the canvas?
2. How can I obtain a canvas with the same color of the background or transparent?

Comment: If you only put one image, you could use `Label(image=img)` to do that.

Comment: The image is too big.  Try to resize it to the required size either using image editing program or `pillow` module.

Comment: The reason you can still see it is because you are setting the anchor to NW. As you image is significantly larger than 250x250, you can still see it. The default anchor is CENTER so just remove that kwarg for the desired behaviour (as @acw1668 has said, you would probably like to reduce the image dimensions). As for having the same background as the window, you are manually setting the canvas bg to white (again, remove this kwarg for the desired behaviour).